# glog throws invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression '@'

Tags: c++, macos, bazel, glog

I am using Bazel importing glog in the workspace as:

```
git_repository(
    name = "com_github_glog_glog",
    commit = "3106945d8d3322e5cbd5658d482c9ffed2d892c0",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/glog.git",
)

bind(
    name = "glog",
    actual = "@com_github_glog_glog//:glog",
)
```

When building glog directly (bazel build external:glog) it works fine, however, when I try to use it as a dependency in one of my build targets I get the following error:

```
bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_glog_glog/_virtual_includes/glog/glog/stl_logging.h:50:6: error: invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression
#if !@ac_cv_cxx_using_operator@
     ^
```

I am on macOS 10.13.2.

Any thoughts on how to address this?  Is it an issue with the compiler on macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in glog solved by https://github.com/google/glog/pull/291

Answer (score 0):

Writing answer so I can formatting. Can you try if the example here https://github.com/google/glog/tree/master/bazel/example works for you? I compile smoothly on linux:

WORKSPACE:

```
git_repository(
    name = "com_github_glog_glog",
    commit = "3106945d8d3322e5cbd5658d482c9ffed2d892c0",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/glog.git",
)

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_gflags_gflags",
    sha256 = "6e16c8bc91b1310a44f3965e616383dbda48f83e8c1eaa2370a215057b00cabe",
    strip_prefix = "gflags-77592648e3f3be87d6c7123eb81cbad75f9aef5a",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/gflags/gflags/archive/77592648e3f3be87d6c7123eb81cbad75f9aef5a.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/gflags/gflags/archive/77592648e3f3be87d6c7123eb81cbad75f9aef5a.tar.gz",
    ],
)

bind(
    name = "glog",
    actual = "@com_github_glog_glog//:glog",
)
```

BUILD

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = [ "foo.cc" ],
    deps = [ "@com_github_glog_glog//:glog" ],
)
```

foo.cc

```
#include <gflags/gflags.h>
#include <glog/logging.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Initialize Google's logging library.
  google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

  // Optional: parse command line flags
  gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);

  LOG(INFO) << "Hello, world!";

  return 0;
}
```